# Run a main from a class using maven

Tags: java

Dear members of support,
I have cloned this repo https://github.com/BrentDouglas/pdfbox and after that made

```
cd examples
```

after that I run

```
mvn clean install
```

That command generates inside of the examples folder a folder target with a jar name pdfbox-examples-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. I am trying to run the main class of org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature using

```
java -cp target/pdfbox-examples-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature
```

But I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature
```

What is wrong with my command? Could you help me, please?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920434/maven-adding-mainclass-in-pom-xml-with-the-right-folder-path

Comment: The jar is not correctly added to your classpath, so it can't find the main class. You do a `cd examples` and then refer to `examples/target/...` in your classpath? You sure this is correct? Shouldn't this be `target/...` as you are already in the examples dir?

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit sorry I fix my question.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments you don't set up the classpath correctly. Since you are already in the examples directory it should be `java -cp target/...`.

But your real problem is that you didn't put all the dependencies into the classpath. You can retrieve the complete classpath by running the following command in the `examples` directory:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

So your final command should look something like this on Unix:

```
java -cp <output of dependency plug-in>:pdfbox-examples-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature
```

Or on Windows:

```
java -cp <output of dependency plug-in>;pdfbox-examples-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature
```

By the way. I think you should use [this repo](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox) as PDFBox has been migrated to the Apache Github organization.

Comment: Or get the pdfbox jar files from maven. The 3.0.0 is the development trunk.