# How to migrate from a NetBeans project into Java CI with Maven in GitHub?

Tags: maven, github-actions

I have a couple of mature projects developed in NetBeans. I want to stop using NetBeans and migrate into a Java CI with Maven in GitHub, so that every time a commit is pushed, a JAR file is created in GitHub. I would also like to keep history in git.

Answer (score 1):

Successfully accomplished that manually by doing this:

1. Get rid of all NetBeans' crap. Delete `nbproject/*`, `build.xml`, `manifest.mf`, ...
2. Correct `src` to include `main/java`. My NetBeans projects sources were stored under `src/package_name`, while in Maven `src/main/java/package_name`.
3. Added Maven's `POM.xml`
4. Added GitHub's workflow file `.github/workflows/maven.yml`, including path to main class to make the JAR file runnable as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920434/maven-adding-mainclass-in-pom-xml-with-the-right-folder-path)

Commit and push those changes into GitHub and your JAR file will be magically created under Actions.

---

File `.github/workflow/maven.yml`

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
    - run: mkdir staging && cp target/*.jar staging
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: Package
        path: staging
```

---

File `pom.xml` (edit to fit your project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your_id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your_artifact_id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I really detest how much rubbish NetBeans creates. Trying to do the same with `ant` and facing a lot of problems. I feel this IDE is a bit too intrusive...

Comment: Interesting start for my nbproject. Thanks :)
Did you manage to automatically transform all the dependencies from the ext folder into maven dependencies?

Comment: And my project is a web project that is deployed on tomcat using nbproject/ant-deploy.xml. Did you manage to automatically transform this deploy task as a GitHub action?

Comment: @adranale my project did not have dependencies so can't say anything about that