# Deploy Java Telegram bot on Heroku: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, heroku, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot by this lib: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots .

The bot can run successfully on my local machine but cannot run on Heroku.
The Error Message is "Counld not find or load main class."

I have read a lot of similar questions but still cannot solve my problem because other questions have some differences from this.

Here are some logs when the error happened on Heroku:

```
2021-05-12T11:51:15.644410+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `sh target/bin/my_bot_test`
2021-05-12T11:51:17.945513+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-12T11:51:19.427171+00:00 app[worker.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2021-05-12T11:51:19.616191+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class Main
2021-05-12T11:51:19.668857+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-12T11:51:19.756822+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Here is the content of `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_bot_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-abilities</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            <name>my_bot_test</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here are some cmds are used for deploy:

```
mvn clean install
git add .
git commit -m "test"
heroku login
git remote add heroku [gitUrl]
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

I referred to this page when studying: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/504-sozdanie-telegram-bota-na-java-ot-idei-do-deploja

The Procfile I wrote this:

```
worker: sh target/bin/my_bot_test
```

I learned that the content of `Procfile` means excute command `target/bin/my_bot_test` in the root directory of project. So I try to excute it on my machine and it runs successfully.

I don't how the error happened and how to solve the problem... Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for <mainClass> provide a fully qualified path in POM. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920434/maven-adding-mainclass-in-pom-xml-with-the-right-folder-path

Comment: @Mayur My main class is in the default package. What should the fully qualified path like? I think it is only the class name just like I written in `pom.xml`: `<mainClass>Main</mainClass>`

Comment: If you're using eclipse the select class name and right click you'll find qualified path else its class file path from project directory.

Comment: @Mayur I solved the problem and I wrote the reason in the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.

The cause of this is Heroku will compile the source code on server not run compiled program directly. So I should push **THE SOURCE CODE** rather than the complied program to the git of Heroku.